# Exclude items from SQL Result

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I may be missing something because I thought this would be a simple task.

I wanted to retrieve results that were not included in Table 3.

Any help?

**Table 1**

```
T1C1  T1C2   

  1     London
  2     New York
  3     Paris
  4     Cardiff  
  5     Bradford
  6     Sydney
  7     Bradford
  8     Beijing
  9     Cairo
```

**Table 2**

```
T2C1  T2C2   

  A     UK
```

**Table 3**

```
T3C1  T3C2   

  1     A
  4     A 
  5     A
  7     A
```

**Result**

```
T1C1  T1C2   

  2    New York
  3    Paris
  6    Sydney
  8    Beijing
  9    Cairo
```

Comment: What role plays `Table 2`? Which query yielded the result? What's wrong with `SELECT T1C1,T1C2  FROM Table1 WHERE T1C1 NOT IN(SELECT T3C1 FROM Table3)`?

Comment: Actually that is the command I was looking for (NOT IN)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `select * from Table1 where T1C1 not in (select T3C1 from Table3)`
2. `select * from Table1 left join Table2 on T1C1=T3C1 where T3C2 IS NULL`
3. `select * from Table1 where not exists (select 1 from Table2 where T1C1=T3C1)`(as suggested by Tim Schmelter in comments)

Comment: ... 3.) select * ftom t1 where not exists(select 1 from t3 where t1.T1C1=t3.T3C1)  This is the most reliable approach.

Comment: Here you find other options and their pros and cons: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: As SQL is declarative one "should not need to" consider performance issues when formulating queries. However, the are some issues in query optimizers. E.g. correlated "not in" queries are problematic in MySQL<6 as those are not optimized at all.

Comment: and `IN()` or `NOT IN()` may not scale well in many dbms/versions too where `|NOT| EXISTS` has been with SQL since inception (literally) and performs well in most cases.

Comment: This is a MS SQL-Server question, isnt it? Its not all about performance but reliability. I really suggest to read the article i've posted in my last comment. In SQL-Server the Join is both, less efficient and less reliable (if the join-column is nullable).

Answer (score 1):

You could just use NOT IN;

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE T1C1 NOT IN (
   SELECT T1C1 FROM Table3
)
```